# When changing handbrake cables, do rear wheels need to be removed?

Tags: brakes

Civic coupe vti 1999.

Handbrake is loose.  I think this mean one or both cables need to be changed.

When doing so, do rear wheels need to be removed or can you just get under the car, remove and add cables without moving wheels?

Thanks.

Comment: On a ramp you may be able to change without removing the wheels. On the ground using a jack and stands it may be easier to remove the wheels.

Comment: Of course, you have checked the adjustment before you decided to replace?

Comment: "Handbrake is loose. I think this mean one or both cables need to be changed." Maybe not, the cables can be adjusted at the hand brake lever, or the rear brakes are far out of adjustment